# How to add webpack externals without running eject in ng CLI?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

quick question on the Angular CLI.

Usually when I'm using webpack, I'm able to register externals within the webpack config (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) for any objects that are saved to the window object. So, if I've got window.foo = bar, I can register that as an external with a name in my webpack.config.js, and then i can

var x = require("foo"); (or import * as foo from 'foo'; in typescript)

wherever I need it.

The problem is that the Angular CLI keeps the webpack config under a black box, and I REALLY don't want to eject from that.

For the full problem I'm experiencing, I need to take this library https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js
and use it in my Angular Typescript project. I'd like to be able to "import * as MSAL from 'msal';", but if you look into the source code for that library, it doesn't actually export it as a module, it just saves it to the window object.

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem for VSTS extensions I need  
externals: [
        /^VSS\/.*/, /^TFS\/.*/, /^q$/
    ], in my webpack config, I have to eject which I don't like